Applying Clenshaw-Curtis on problematic cases
I am considering the application of the Clenshaw-Curtis quadrature to integrate functions with the following characteristics:

The function has derivatives that exist only up to a finite order $k$ (i.e., the function is $k$-times differentiable, but not infinitely differentiable).
The function has poles or singularities that are close to the integration interval $[-1, 1]$.

I understand that Clenshaw-Curtis quadrature is typically effective for smooth functions, as it uses Chebyshev nodes and interpolation, but I am concerned about the impact of these two factors (limited smoothness and nearby poles) on the quadrature's performance.
What are the main challenges and issues that arise when applying Clenshaw-Curtis quadrature to such functions? Specifically:

How does the limited smoothness (i.e., only $k$-times differentiable functions) affect the accuracy and convergence of the method?
What are the problems associated with the presence of poles near the interval $[-1, 1]$, especially when these poles are close to the endpoints or the function exhibits singular behavior near them?
I am also interested in an adaptive Clenshaw-Curtis algorithm that will adaptively increase the order of precision based on earlier results. How can such an algorithm be formulated, and what challenges arise in its implementation? For now, I am just planning to implement this algorithm for smooth functions ($C^{\infty}-$functions).

Thank you in advance for your insights!
